# use GPUImage to add a watermark for a video, catch a error such `tried to overrelease a frame buffer`

Tags: ios, objective-c

it makes me confused because sometimes only after you test 5-6 times can it appear, but sometimes you just test 1 more.this is my code:

```
UIImage *coverImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
UIImageView *coverImageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:coverImage1];
[coverImageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, size.height-100, 210, 50)];


UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[subView addSubview:coverImageView1];

GPUImageUIElement *uielement = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:subView];
NSString *pathToMovie =string;
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(720.0, 1280.0)];

GPUImageFilter* progressFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
[progressFilter addTarget:filter];
[movieFile addTarget:progressFilter];
[uielement addTarget:filter];
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[filter addTarget:movieWriter];
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];
[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[progressFilter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *output, CMTime time) {
    [uielement update];
}];
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf->filter removeTarget:strongSelf->movieWriter];
        [strongSelf->movieWriter finishRecording];
        [uielement useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        //[[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache]purgeAllUnassignedFramebuffers];
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(strongSelf->string, strongSelf, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    });
}];
```

I tried to move the `[uielement useNextFrameForImageCapture];` inside `[progressFilter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock...]`,but it doesn't work either

Comment: I think it may be the Memory hasn't been released when you use the filter last time, but I don't know how to solve it....

Comment: I try toremove the line [uielement useNextForImageCapture]